# Javascript Array with String Key

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript create a array with string Key.?

eg:-

```
arr[0]['col1']="Firstname";
arr[0]['col2']="Lastname";

arr[1]['col1']="firstname1";
arr[1]['col2']="lastname2";
```

Comment: Arrays are just objects with a special length property and methods inherited from *Array.prototype*. The "keys" or "indexes" are standard object property names and are just numeric strings. When numbers are used as property names, they are first converted to strings, e.g. `a[1]` is the same as `a["1"]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it's called an object, not an array.

```
arr = [{col1: 'Firstname', col2: 'Lastname'},
    {col1: 'Firstname', col2: 'Lastname'}];
```

You can access (assign or retrieve) the values by `arr[0]['col1']` and even `arr[0].col1`.

EDIT: For clarification the data structure that looks like an array with string keys is called an *object*.  This example is still using an array (with numeric keys).

Comment: Actually, this is an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You'll most likely want to use an [object literal](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2138-how-to-use-object-literals-in-javascript/):

```
var studentAges = {
  sara: 14,
  mike: 17,
  daniel: 15,
  Jake: 14
};
```

There are no associate arrays in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using objects:

```
var ar = [
    {  col1: "...", col2: "..." },
    {  col1: "...", col2: "..." },
];
```